# How to decrease the barthickness in ng2-charts?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts, angular12

[barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvMPR.png)

html file

```
  <canvas width="3" height="1"
                  *ngIf="loaded"
                  baseChart
                  [data]="barChartData"
                  [labels]="barChartLabels"
                  [options]="barChartOptions"
                  [legend]="barChartLegend"
                  [chartType]="barChartType"
                  [colors]="chartColors"
                >
                </canvas>
```

ts file

```
 chartColors: Array<any> = [
    {
      // all colors in order
      backgroundColor: ['#2EA082', '#2B2272', '#A687FF'],
    },
  ];
  barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },

    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            callback: function (value: number, index, values) {
              return '$ ' + Intl.NumberFormat().format(value / 100000) + 'K';
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      xAxes: [
        {
          gridLines: {
            lineWidth: 0,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  barChartLabels: string[] = [];
  barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  barChartLegend: boolean = true;
  barChartData: any[] = [];
  loaded = false;
```

I'm using chartjs 2.9.4 and ng2 2.4.2 version. how to reduce bar thickness and also i tried using barThickness under xAxes but it is not working. I have attached the image for reference

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dataset option `barPercentage` as described [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration).

In you code, this could look as follows:

```
barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
  {
    label: 'My Dataset',
    data: [65, 56, 40],    
    barPercentage: 0.5
  }
];
```

Comment: I m getting values from api to barChartData and unable to deploy your code in that place.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert static data for testing purpose and set barThickness property instead of barPercentage. It worked for me.